Closed formula for Kernel and Column Space of a Matrix to Span $\mathbb R^3$
Given the matrix $ M(a) $ defined as:
$ M(a) $ = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & a \\
-1 & a & 2 \\
a & 2 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
Determine for which values of $ a \in \mathbb{R} $ the following condition holds:
$ \ker(M(a)) + \operatorname{Col}(M(a)) = \mathbb{R}^3 $
Is there a closed formula for this? I tried plugging values for a and tried to work from there but I didnt find an answer.

You can do this case by case: $\text{det}M(a)=3a-a^3-2=-(a-1)^2(a+2)$. For generic $a$, $M(a)$ is invertible, so clealy the column space is already $\mathbb R^3$.
If $a=1$, the column is spaned by $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and kernel is spanned by $\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}$, thus kernel and column doesn't span $\mathbb R^3$. If $a=-2$, the column is spanned by $\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and kernel is spanned by $\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}$. In this case column and kernel span $\mathbb R^3$.

I understand your approach, Thanks!
In the case of a=1, It doesn't span $\mathbb R^3$ but i get the idea.
